# Get Blogger.com JSON data back into a html format?

Tags: javascript, json

Bit of a complicated issue.

I've been looking at ways of getting data into a PhoneGap App so the info in the App can be changed without having to update via the appstore on every change.

After a lot of looking around I've found that Blogger.com has a JSON output that I THINK I can tap into and pull the data into the app.

PhoneGap pages have to be .html so I cant use a .php or .net page to get data.

Im told that if I can get JSON data I can use JS to get data out of the feed and use it... so......

Ive set up a test blog and using this url i can get a JSON feed:

http://ironheartuk123.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc

This is what the feed outputs:

```
// API callback
myFunc({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$blogger":"http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008","xmlns$georss":"http://www.georss.org/georss","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","xmlns$thr":"http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0","id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5655651846573938667"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-11-28T02:41:47.924-08:00"},"title":{"type":"text","$t":"test"},"subtitle":{"type":"html","$t":""},"link":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/feeds\/posts\/default"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/5655651846573938667\/posts\/default?alt=json-in-script"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/"},{"rel":"hub","href":"http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Mark Latham"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/16519153095270236038"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"16","height":"16","src":"http:\/\/img2.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"}}],"generator":{"version":"7.00","uri":"http://www.blogger.com","$t":"Blogger"},"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"2"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":"25"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5655651846573938667.post-5882120439717312684"},"published":{"$t":"2014-11-28T02:41:00.003-08:00"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-11-28T02:41:47.937-08:00"},"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Test post 2"},"content":{"type":"html","$t":"Test post 2"},"link":[{"rel":"replies","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/feeds\/5882120439717312684\/comments\/default","title":"Post Comments"},{"rel":"replies","type":"text/html","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/2014\/11\/test-post-2.html#comment-form","title":"0 Comments"},{"rel":"edit","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/5655651846573938667\/posts\/default\/5882120439717312684"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/5655651846573938667\/posts\/default\/5882120439717312684"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/2014\/11\/test-post-2.html","title":"Test post 2"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Mark Latham"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/16519153095270236038"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"16","height":"16","src":"http:\/\/img2.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"}}],"thr$total":{"$t":"0"}},{"id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5655651846573938667.post-8794205203420774123"},"published":{"$t":"2014-11-28T02:41:00.001-08:00"},"updated":{"$t":"2014-11-28T02:41:19.714-08:00"},"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Test Post 1"},"content":{"type":"html","$t":"Test post 1"},"link":[{"rel":"replies","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/feeds\/8794205203420774123\/comments\/default","title":"Post Comments"},{"rel":"replies","type":"text/html","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/2014\/11\/test-post-1.html#comment-form","title":"0 Comments"},{"rel":"edit","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/5655651846573938667\/posts\/default\/8794205203420774123"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/5655651846573938667\/posts\/default\/8794205203420774123"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http:\/\/ironheartuk123.blogspot.com\/2014\/11\/test-post-1.html","title":"Test Post 1"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Mark Latham"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/16519153095270236038"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"16","height":"16","src":"http:\/\/img2.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"}}],"thr$total":{"$t":"0"}}]}});
```

The blog has to posts 'Test Post 1' and 'Test Post 2' - I'd like to use JS to end up with something like this:

```
<div><!-- Data from test post 1--></div>

<div><!-- Data from test post 2--></div>
```

I need a JS script to pull the data and put into the divs? Possible?!?!

Comment: Please be more specific. In general this is possible. Yes, you need some JS and the technique blogspot provides is called JSONP. Maybe you should look into something like jQuery and especially into the [`jQuery.getJSON` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). jQuery also provides ways for the manipulation of the html page. Feel free to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Ok, I thought i was quite specific ;-)

I need a script that can get the JSON data from the url (above) and put the content from the blog posts into Divs on a HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the JS that I finally got to work:

function posts(json) {

```
  // Get five recent posts
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    var posturl;  
    // Get rel=alternate for truly post url
    for (var j=0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++)
    {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate')
      {
        posturl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
        break;
      }
    }
    // if the Blogger-feed is set to FULL, then the content is in the content-field
    // if the Blogger-feed is set to SHORT, then the content is in the summary-field
    if ("content" in json.feed.entry[i]) {
      var postcontent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;}
    else
    if ("summary" in json.feed.entry[i]) {
      var postcontent = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;}
    else var postcontent = "";
    // strip off all html-tags
    // reduce postcontent to 200 characters
    if (postcontent.length > 200) postcontent = postcontent.substring(0,200);
    // Get posts title
    document.write("<div class='blogger-post' id='post" + json.feed.entry[i].id.$t.split('post')[1] + "'>" + postcontent + "</div>");    
  }
    }
```